# javafx - Draw circle on button click

Tags: javafx

I made a circle in using fxml sheet. Now I'd like to move that circle around with the click of a button. It's simple and works, but I want to have a same looking circle stay at the same position the original was on when I click the button.

```
private void click0(javafx.event.ActionEvent event) {

    Circle c0d = c0;
    c0d.setCenterX(600);
    c0d.setCenterY(900);
    c0d.setRadius(32.0f);


    TranslateTransition translate = new TranslateTransition(
            Duration.millis(750));
    translate.setToX(1);
    translate.setToY(432);

    ParallelTransition transition = new ParallelTransition(c0,translate);
    transition.setCycleCount(1);
    transition.play();

}
```

I can make a new instance of the circle with the properties of the original one, but how do i draw it on the same position as the original one?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this :

```
import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;


public class Circles extends Application {

     Group root;
     Scene scene;
     Button button;


    @Override
    public void start(Stage s) {     

        root = new Group();
        scene = new Scene(root, 250, 350);
        button = new Button();
        button.setText("create circle");

    root.getChildren().add(button);
    s.setScene(scene);
    s.show();

   button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

       @Override
       public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
        Circle r = new Circle();
            r.setCenterX(90f);
            r.setCenterY(90f);
            r.setRadius(32.0f);

            r.setFill(Color.ORANGE);

       TranslateTransition translate = new TranslateTransition(
               Duration.millis(5000));
       translate.setToX(1);
       translate.setToY(432);


    ParallelTransition transition = new ParallelTransition(r,translate);
       transition.setCycleCount(1); 
       transition.play();
       root.getChildren().add(r);

       }
   });
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Application.launch(args);

    }

}
```

Comment: @Ajay_C, if this isn't what you want feel free to tell me.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
The code should be working but i get a 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Children: duplicate children added: parent = Grid hgap=0.0, vgap=0.0, alignment=TOP_LEFT